# CANBUS API Development

Tags: c#-4.0, protocols, can-bus

I would like to develop canbus API development where I can send the FRAME details and others like startbit, stopbits, priority  and through C# language development. Can anybody providing the structure of data to be sent through CANBUS. I have already tested the serial port communication but how will i develop any interface developed on C# or python language. The interface will help to send the required data through CANBUS Protocol to microcontroller.

I am trying to develop the interface where I will send the data frame through CANBUS protocol. If there is any open project or any resources on the basis of which I can develop the interface .

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send CAN frames from an ordinary PC unless you have some kind of CAN Bus hardware. Serial port simply won't do. Nowadays, there are USB to CAN Bus adapters (hardware) on the market, and they almost always come with some kind of API, so you basically use that.